# Issue debugging c code using gdb in linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WATas.jpg)

I'm trying to debug a code in linux using gdb, first time using it. Can someone point out what's wrong in my processes or is this a normal occurance due to the code?

The code is

```c
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[100];
    long int n1;
    int fd1, fd2;

    if (((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) ||
        ((fd2 = open(argv[2], O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC,0700)) == -1)) {
        perror("file problem ");  
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((n1 = read(fd1, buffer, 512) > 0))
        if (write(fd2, buffer, n1) != n1) {
            perror("writing problem ");
            exit(3);
        }

    // in Case of an error exit from the loop  
    if (n1 == -1) {
        perror("Reading problem ");
        exit(2);
    }
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);  
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `n1=read(fd1, buffer, 512` That will cause a buffer overflow. `buffer` is only 100 bytes yet you tell `read` it can write 512 bytes. Change to `(n1=read(fd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the code and error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as images. You have correctly pasted the code. Please, do the same with the error message. See also [ask].